# Could someone please explain this filter graph?

Tags: c, ffmpeg, libav

https://www.ffmpeg.org/doxygen/trunk/filtering_video_8c-example.html

```c
    filter_graph = avfilter_graph_alloc();
    // ...
    const AVFilter *buffersrc  = avfilter_get_by_name("buffer");
    const AVFilter *buffersink = avfilter_get_by_name("buffersink");
    // ...
    /* buffer video source: the decoded frames from the decoder will be inserted here. */
    snprintf(args, sizeof(args),
            "video_size=%dx%d:pix_fmt=%d:time_base=%d/%d:pixel_aspect=%d/%d",
            dec_ctx->width, dec_ctx->height, dec_ctx->pix_fmt,
            time_base.num, time_base.den,
            dec_ctx->sample_aspect_ratio.num, dec_ctx->sample_aspect_ratio.den);
 
    ret = avfilter_graph_create_filter(&buffersrc_ctx, buffersrc, "in",
                                       args, NULL, filter_graph);
    /* buffer video sink: to terminate the filter chain. */
    ret = avfilter_graph_create_filter(&buffersink_ctx, buffersink, "out",
                                       NULL, NULL, filter_graph);
    // ...
/*
     * Set the endpoints for the filter graph. The filter_graph will
     * be linked to the graph described by filters_descr.
     */
 
    /*
     * The buffer source output must be connected to the input pad of
     * the first filter described by filters_descr; since the first
     * filter input label is not specified, it is set to "in" by
     * default.
     */
    outputs->name       = av_strdup("in");
    outputs->filter_ctx = buffersrc_ctx;
    outputs->pad_idx    = 0;
    outputs->next       = NULL;
 
    /*
     * The buffer sink input must be connected to the output pad of
     * the last filter described by filters_descr; since the last
     * filter output label is not specified, it is set to "out" by
     * default.
     */
    inputs->name       = av_strdup("out");
    inputs->filter_ctx = buffersink_ctx;
    inputs->pad_idx    = 0;
    inputs->next       = NULL;
 
    if ((ret = avfilter_graph_parse_ptr(filter_graph, filters_descr,
                                    &inputs, &outputs, NULL)) < 0)
```

So I see these parts separately like this:

[image]

But I can't combine them in my head.
Are these `in` and `out` filters the same everywhere?
What filter or graph are these `inputs` and `outputs`? If the parsed graph takes the input from `in` filter, why is it (`in` filter) in `outputs` variable then (and vice versa)!? What is even the role of these variables?
Could you please explain the step by step algorithm how this code works

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Are these in and out filters the same everywhere?

They are the input and output buffers for `filter_descr` which must be a filter chain (single input, single output). If you have MIMO filtergraph, `inputs` and `outputs` would be arrays, each of their elements allocated by `avfilter_inout_alloc()`.

> What filter or graph are these inputs and outputs?

They are for the filter graph is defined in `filter_descr`

> If the parsed graph takes the input from in filter, why is it (in filter) in outputs variable then (and vice versa)!? What is even the role of these variables?

Edited: They are treating (the decoder + `buffersrc`) as a source system which `outputs` frames to the `in` pads of `filter_descr` filtergraph, and (`buffersink` + the encoder) as a destination system which receives its `inputs` from the `out` pads of `filter_descr` filtergraph. Thus the variable naming conventions in this example.

Obviously, they are just variable naming convention, and I do agree with you to have them named backwards but |:shrug:|. Rename them so you won't get confused later. I remember going through the same years ago so I 100% understand.

Original answer below

Filtergraph itself should be defined in the string `filters_descr` which is parsed by `avfilter_graph_parse_ptr()`. Say a simple scaling `filters_descr = "[in]scale=iw/2:-1[out]"`. This filtergraph has one filter `scale` which takes 1 input (has 1 input pad) and 1 output (has 1 output pad). `[in]` and `[out]` are the labels for these I/O pads.

Now, when implementing this filter, you need to connect `[in]` and `[out]` pads to the decoder and encoder, respectively. For that, you use `buffersrc` and `buffersink` endpoint filters so the data frames can be in/out of the graph. But, these filters are not explicitly specified in `filters_descr`. Thus, in the code snippet, these endpoint filters are created by `avfilter_graph_create_filter()` functions, and you can note that their pads are named as `"in"` and `"out"` accordingly.

Finally, `avfilter_graph_parse_ptr` creates a network as specified by `filters_descr` and connect `inputs` and `outputs` (they could be arrays to support filtergraphs with multiple inputs and outputs.

Comment: Why is `in` filter in the `outputs` array, if it's used as an input? I don't get it

Comment: It's just their naming convention, from the perspectives of the decoder & encoder. outputs of decoder map to the `in` pads of the filtergraph, and inputs of encoder get data from `out` pads of the filtergraph (well, that's my quick take, I need to review `avfilter_graph_parse_ptr()` first as I haven't dealt with the API in awhile

Comment: Check out [the source code of `avfilter_graph_parse_ptr()`](https://github.com/FFmpeg/FFmpeg/blob/master/libavfilter/graphparser.c#L549).

Comment: So these `inputs` are filters, that the parsed graph is able to connect its outputs to?
(And vice versa)

Comment: Yes, you got it. I edited the answer a bit as well. See if it makes more sense.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/242439/discussion-between-wynell-and-kesh).